# Replace string with part of the matching regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string. I want to replace all the matches with part of the matching regex (group).

For example:

```
String = "This is a great day, is it not? If there is something, THIS IS it. <b>is</b>".
```

I want to replace all the words `"is"` by, let's say, `"<h1>is</h1>"`. The case should remain the same as original. So the final string I want is:

```
This <h1>is</h1> a great day, <h1>is</h1> it not? If there <h1>is</h1> something, 
THIS <h1>IS</h1> it. <b><h1>is</h1></b>.
```

The regex I was trying:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.>, ](is)[.<, ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: The pattern matches fine. What I don't understand is how to replace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Matcher` class is commonly used in conjunction with `Pattern`.  Use the `Matcher.replaceAll()` method to replace all matches in the string

```
String str = "This is a great day...";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bis\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String result = m.replaceAll("<h1>is</h1>");
```

**Note:** Using the `\b` regex command will match on a word boundary (like whitespace).  This is helpful to use in order to ensure that only the word "is" is matched and not words that contain the letters "i" and "s" (like "island").

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll(yourRegex, "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

The `$1` refers to the text captured by group #1 in your regex.

Comment: The downside to this solution is that it will always be case-sensitive.  There's no way to define the regex to be case-insensitive.

Comment: @Michael - Just include a `(?i)` modifier at the beginning of the regex if you need case insensitivity.

Comment: Oh didn't know that.  Ignore my comment. :(

Comment: Just so you know, you helped someone 6 years to the future!

Comment: I also wanted to thank you. I haven't found a way to replace text by text found by some group before!

Answer (score 3):

Michael's answer is better, but if you happen to specifically only want `[.>, ]` and `[.<, ]` as boundaries, you can do it like this:

```
String input = "This is a great day, is it not? If there is something, THIS IS it. <b>is</b>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=[.>, ])(is)(?=[.<, ])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String result = m.replaceAll("<h1>$1</h1>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourStr.replaceAll("(?i)([.>, ])(is)([.<, ])","$1<h1>$2</h1>$3")
```

`(?i)`to indicate ignoring case; wrap everything your want to reuse with brackets, reuse them with $1 $2 and $3, concatenate them into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a backreference for that.

```java
"This is a great day, is it not? If there is something, THIS IS it. <b>is</b>"
  .replaceAll("[.>, ](is)[.<, ]", "<h1>$2</h1>");
```

should do.

Comment: Again, you cannot tell the regex to be case-insensitive with this solution.

Comment: Nevermind, you can prepend the regex string with `(?i)` to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a late addition, but if anyone is looking for this like
Searching for `thing` and also he needs `Something` too to be taken as result

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^ ]*)is([^ \\.]*)");
String result = m.replaceAll("<\h1>$1is$2<\/h1>");
```

will result `Something` too