# Read a paragraph from the user and replace specific words In java

Tags: java

How Would we write a program using Java to read a paragraph from the user and replace specific words mentioned in a vector to the following format, i.e.,

For example word `Happy` is reduced to `H****`.

Any Help will be Appriciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class replaceString {

     public static String putStars(String str) {
        char first_char = str.charAt(0);

        String ans = new String();
        ans = String.valueOf(first_char);

        for(int i = 1;i < str.length(); ++i ) {
            ans = ans + "*";
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static String replaceWords(String str, Vector<String> v1) {
        String[] words = str.split("\\W+"); //split across all types of punctuation

        String ansString = new String();

            for(String to_be_replaced : words) {
                boolean found = false;

                for(String to_replace_with : v1) {

                if(to_be_replaced.equals(to_replace_with)) {
                    //System.out.println("in");
                    ansString = ansString +putStars(to_be_replaced) +  " ";
                    found = true;

                }
            }  
                if(found == false) {
                    ansString = ansString + to_be_replaced + " ";
                }

        }
        return ansString;
    }

        public static String replaceWords1(String str, Vector<String> v1) {

        for(String currStr : v1) {
            str.replace(str, );
        }

        return ansString;
    } 


    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the paragraph that you would like to edit ");

        String s = br.readLine();

        // Let us assume some strings in our very own vector

        Vector<String> v1 = new Vector<String>();

        v1.addElement("Hello");
        v1.addElement("Hi");
        v1.addElement("Heya");
        v1.addElement("Howdy");
        v1.addElement("Howu");

        String ans = replaceWords(s, v1);

        System.out.println("Paragraph after replacement becomes\n\n"+ ans);
    }
}
```

this is my current code but its not working fine

Comment: Iterate over the words of the input paragraph (`Scanner` and its `.next()` method), check whether they are in your vector, if so replace them with their first character concatenated to the word's length minus one asterisks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], read [ask] and show your efforts in a [mcve] form. This isn't a free coding service, but a Q & A site, where you need to ask specific questions. As is, your question is too broad as it lacks research / effort into solving it yourself and thus, might get closed

Comment: Can you please explain with help of some code it would be better as i am completely new to it

Comment: *"Can you please explain with help of some code"* Please post your efforts first, no one is going to provide "free code" or do your homework for you!

Comment: i have added code

Comment: *"this is my current code but its not working fine"* What does "not working fine" means?

Comment: it didn't change Happy to H****.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be other possibilities, but here's an example I did based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866082/2180785):

1. We need all the words we need / want to match, and store them in an array:

   ```
   String [] words = {"appy", "eya", "dy"};
   ```
2. (Optional) If you really need a `Vector`, I suggest to create a `List` (`ArrayList`) instead, and we can do it this way:

   ```
   List <String> wordsToReplace = Arrays.asList(words);
   ```

   Otherwise just modify the method in the next step to receive an array...
3. We create a function that receives this `List` and the phrase we want to check for and that returns the new `String` with the replaced text in it

So, our whole code ends up like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordReplacer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] words = {"appy", "eya", "dy"};

        List <String> wordsToReplace = Arrays.asList(words);

        System.out.println(replaceWords("Happy", wordsToReplace));
        System.out.println(replaceWords("Heya", wordsToReplace));
        System.out.println(replaceWords("Howdy?", wordsToReplace));
        System.out.println(replaceWords("Howdy? My friend lives in Pompeya and every time I see her I say \"Heya\" to her, she is very happy", wordsToReplace));
    }

    private static String replaceWords(String word, List <String> wordsToReplace) {
        for (String s : wordsToReplace) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); //We create a pattern that matches each word in our list. (1)
            Matcher m = p.matcher(word); //We actually check for each match against our phrase
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (m.find()) { //If there was a match, we're going to replace each character for an '*' (2)
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    sb.append("*");
                }
            }

            word = m.replaceAll(sb.toString()); //We replace each match with '*' (3)
        }

        return word; //We return the modified word
    }
}
```

I'm going to explain what each comment (1), (2), (3) do in a better and simpler way:

- (1) As shown in the linked answer, they use `\b` regex command to match whole words, but in this case we're using it to match parts of words, not whole words, so we don't need it here...
- (2) Only if we found a match we fill the `StringBuilder` with `*` characters... If we didn't do it this way, we would be getting: `H*` instead of `H****` for the case of `Happy` word, this way we ensure we get the correct amount of `*` for every word in the `List`.
- (3) We replace the matches for the total number of `*` in the `StringBuilder` so we get the correct output.

The program above produces the following output:

```
H****
H***
How**?
How**? My friend lives in Pomp*** and every time I see her I say "H***" to her, she is very h****
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that with a map that contains yours replacing rules :

```
    String input; //input string
    Map<String,String> mapReplace = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mapReplace.put("Hello","H****");
    Iterator<String> keys = mapReplace.keySet().iterator();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next();
        input = input.replace(input, mapReplace.get(key));
    }
```